# Probability Density Function of Random Variable which is Sum of other Random Variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X_0, X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ each be non-identical independent random variables.

Let $x_0, x_1, ... , x_n$ be possible values of each of those random variables.

Let $\newcommand{\Pdf}{\operatorname {Pdf}} \Pdf_{X_0}(x_{0}), \Pdf_{X_1}(x_{1}), ... , \Pdf_{X_n}(x_{n})$ represent each of random variables corresponding probability density functions.

$X_0$ has probability density function $\Pdf_{X_0}(x_0)$ ,

$X_1$ has probability density function $\Pdf_{X_1}(x_1)$ ... etc...

---

Lets say we know explicitly, analytically, exactly what all the $Pdf$'s are above.

---

Now Let $Y = X_0 + X_1 + X_2, ... + X_n$ which has probability density function $\Pdf_Y(y)$.

What is $\Pdf_Y(y)$ ?

How do I calculate it with the information above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a well known (and important) result that the density of the sum of independent random variables is the [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions) of the individual densities.

See for example [here](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter7.pdf) or [here](http://www3.nd.edu/~cstanton/courses/math30530/lecture26.pdf) or [here](https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-probability/sums-of-independent-random-variables).

---

Let $\tau_{0}, \tau_{1}, ... \tau_{n-1}$ represent temporary variables which are integrated out as part of the convolution.

Let $PDF_{x_{a} + x_{b}} $ denote the PDF of only two random variable $X_a + X_b$

$PDF_{x_{a} + x_{b}}(t) = PDF_{x_{a}} * PDF_{x_{a}} (t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} PDF_{x_{a}}( \tau )  PDF_{x_{a}}( t - \tau ) d\tau $

Then the following follows:

$PDF_y(y) = PDF_{x0}*PDF_{x1}*PDF_{x2}*...*PDF_{xn}(y)$
$= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}...\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  
PDF_{x0}(\tau_{0}) PDF_{x1}(\tau_{1} - \tau_{0})  PDF_{x2}(\tau_{2} - \tau_{1} )  ...  PDF_{xn}(y - \tau_{(n-1)}) d\tau_{0} d\tau_{1} ... d\tau_{(n-1)}  $